# iPad uiviewcontroller - why are bounds and frame different sizes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

In xcode 4.5.1, start a single view iOS application project, and in the plist or the target settings, make it support only landscape left and right orientations. Then in the ViewController, put this in:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"bounds: %.2f,%.2f",self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"frame:  %.2f,%.2f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

and you get this when you run it:

```
bounds: 1024.00,748.00
frame:  748.00,1024.00
```

Any ideas why? It's causing all kinds of problems for me with transitions, coreanimation layers etc etc. It seems that something like the CALayer for the view is still in portrait despite the view being landscape.

edit:

if you try something like this:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 2.2;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

notice that it comes from right instead of bottom, and the new view overlaps the old one because it's doing it based on portrait dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

The bounds of an `UIView` is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The frame of an `UIView` is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the `superview` it is contained within.

So, you are getting this result.

Comment: so how can i change the uiview's coordinate system to match its superview's? the view is in landscape, so its frame size should be 1024,768

Comment: i should have been clearer in the original question - i understand that bounds and frame are different things, so by "why" i meant why is the frame wrong

Comment: @jonydep Result whatever you are getting is proper, don't worry. So self.view is not used and self.bounds is used as its represents value in your own co-ordinate system, i.e. landscape or portrait

Comment: but when i try to do any kind of coreanimation transitions etc, it is wrong - the dimensions and rotation are as if it is portrait.

Comment: rotating to the other landscape orientation and then back again fixes it by the way (frame size is from then onwards the same as bounds size)

Comment: so I said you should use self.view.bounds everywhere

Comment: see the edit in the original question for an example of the problems it causes. i'm not explicitly referring to either frame OR bounds